# Event handler not setting state

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Sorry about *another one* of these but I'm at a loss. I am adding an event listener inside of `useEffect()`. The event fires (`console.log()` prints as expected) but the state isn't getting updated. Could someone please explain to me what's going on here and how to solve this problem? Thanks!

```
export default function MyProgress() {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState({ message: "", progress: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleProgress(e: ProgressEvent<EventTarget>) {
      console.log(e.loaded);
      setLoading({message: "Processing Data", progress: e.loaded});
    }

    document.addEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
    };
  }, []);

return (
  <div>
    <p>{loading.message}</p>
    <Progress value={loading.progress} />
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: If you pass some state into the effect..   `}, [foo]);` the effect *acts* as your listener .. Anytime `foo` is changed IE `setFoo('this')` .. The hook will fire ..  So with that said, your paradigm is a little skewed.  There is no need for a listener INSIDE an effect.

Comment: We could be of more assistance if you would share the `handleProgess()` function or state, as well as the element you are listing for the change on ..

Comment: add `console.log(loading)` after `useEffect` call to see if the state has been updated.

Comment: This really needs more debugging details. What specifically is not being updated as expected, and how are you testing it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Zak. `handleProgress()` is in the code I shared and the element being listened to is `document`. As for your first comment, I am not sure I understand. I thought adding event listeners to `document` inside `useEffect()` was pretty standard practice and I don't know how else to listen to the custom `Progress` event...

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jayatubi. I of course did that and no, `loading` is not updating. That's what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BrianThompson. I've added some minimal code to make it clearer. However, as I originally said, the problem is that the state (`loading`) isn't being updated (by `setLoading()`) from the event handler, even though the even is being handled (`consoleLog()` works).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that the event listener function `handleProgress` captures the initial state of loading when it is defined. Therefore, when `setLoading` is called inside `handleProgress`, it is using the initial state and not the updated state.

To solve this problem, you can utilize the functional form of `setLoading` provided by React's `useState` hook. This form of `setLoading` allows you to update the state based on the previous state.

Here is the code to correctly update the state based on the previous state:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState({ message: "", progress: 0 });

useEffect(() => {
  function handleProgress(e: ProgressEvent<EventTarget>) {
    console.log(e.loaded);
    setLoading(prevLoading => ({
      ...prevLoading,
      message: "Processing Data",
      progress: e.loaded
    }));
  }

  document.addEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried this before posting and it's not working either.

Answer (score -1):

State behaves like snapshot. The set function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

you may check it using html like `<span>{loading}</span>`.

Ref: [React useState documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value)
[React state Snapshot documenation](https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot)